# how to get the records of different dates in a dim tale using SQL Presto?

Tags: sql, date, presto

I have a table like this which is a dim table (means all the records in ds are in ds+1 plus the new records added) partition by ds( date):

| ds | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1 | 1 |
| 1/1 | 2 |
| 1/2 | 1 |
| 1/2 | 2 |
| 1/2 | 3 |
| 1/2 | 4 |
| 1/3 | 1 |
| 1/3 | 2 |
| 1/3 | 3 |
| 1/3 | 4 |
| 1/3 | 5 |

I want to calculate: (number of id in ds - number of id in ds_1) / number of id in ds_1 over time or percentage of new ids over time.

the output result is as below:

| ds | % of number of id change |
| --- | --- |
| 1/2 | 100% |
| 1/3 | 25% |

Comment: How many unique ids do you have?

Answer (score 0):

One option to solve this problem is:

- aggregating to get the counts for each ds
- compute (num_of_counts - num_of_counts_prev)/num_of_counts_prev *100 to get the percentage

You can compute the previous number of counts using the `LAG` window function.

```
WITH counts AS (
    SELECT ds, COUNT(ds) AS cnt
    FROM tab
    GROUP BY ds
)
SELECT ds, ROUND(100.0*(cnt - LAG(cnt) OVER w) / LAG(cnt) OVER w) AS "% number of id change"
FROM counts
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY ds)
```

Output:

| ds | % number of id change |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1 | null |
| 1/2 | 100 |
| 1/3 | 25 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gMaE3YxpoAWy19dY8p4juQ/0).